# После установки Hyper-V долго загружается Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, hyper-v, wsl

После включения компонента Hyper-V на Windows 10 Pro, загрузочный экран(чёрный экран с логотипом Windows и кружочками) стал висеть по несколько минут. До включения данного компонента Windows загружалась за считанные секунды, и загрузочный экран иногда не успевал появиться даже. Данный компонент мне необходим для использования Docker'a, отказался от WSL поскольку процесс vmmem поглощал оперативку как бешеный.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180717-00/?p=99265#:~:text=The%20vmmem%20process%20is%20a,of%20memory%20and%20CPU%20resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснил причину долгой загрузки... И о боже как долго я смеялся. Hyper-V здесь вообще не причём был. Я открыл bootlog файл и увидел проблему с загрузкой CAD.sys драйвера. Загуглил и как оказалось у меня в card reader был установлен адаптер на microSD карточки пустой, как только я его вытащил всё прошло. Винда стала запускаться как и раньше быстро и выключаться тоже стала очень быстро.

Answer (score -1):

Если включить Hyper-V, перезагрузить для активации,а потом еще раз перезагрузить то комп все равно долго стартует?
Если проблема наблюдается, только при включении компа, то попробуйте отключить fastboot в Windows.

Также рекомендую установить WSL 2, Docker позволяет выбрать его в качестве  хоста. Сам WSL 2 работает на Hyper-V, и если не ошибаюсь, то не требует включении Hyper-V в компонентах.

Comment: Fastboot отключён. Да даже после перезагрузки долго стартует. Экран с логотипом Windows и кружочками висит по 3-5 минут. Отказался от WSL поскольку сьедает оперативку безнаказанно.

Comment: Единственное что могу предложить еще попробровать: удалить все свитчи в hyper-v и отключить secure boot в bios,если включен

Comment: Тоже не помогло( Глянуть бы логи какие нибудь, чтоб найти причину